# How to make any array of Simple Products Sku in Magento

Tags: php, magento

I want to create a array of all sku's of simple products in magento. can anyone guide me here.

Note: Need to be done by built-in functions without querying database directly. i have different Configurable items in database which have multiple Simple Products. I want to make a array of all simple products rather then configurabale items identification.

```
array(  SKU1, SKU2, SKU3....SKU1000 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way using built-in methods would be:

```
$oCollection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToFilter(
        'type_id',
        array('eq' => 'simple')
    );

$aSku = array();
foreach ($oCollection as $oProduct) {
    $aSku[] = $oProduct->getSku();
}

var_dump($aSku);
```

Comment: The second half could be done with the [`getAllAttributeValues()`](http://docs.magentocommerce.com/Mage_Catalog/Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Product_Collection.html#getAllAttributeValues) method.